docker-compose can not create service containers
I have this "simple" docker-compose.yml from my open source project GPS Tracker:
services:
    gpstracker-mysql:
        image: mysql:8.0
        container_name: gpstracker-mysql
        restart: unless-stopped
        volumes:
            - ./../storage/docker/db:/var/lib/mysql
        environment:
            - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
            - MYSQL_USER=gpstracker
            - MYSQL_PASSWORD=gpstracker
            - MYSQL_DATABASE=gpstracker
        command:
            - --character-set-server=utf8
            - --collation-server=utf8_unicode_ci
        networks:
            - gpstracker-network
        healthcheck:
            test: mysqladmin ping -h localhost --password=root
            interval: 15s
            retries: 15

    gpstracker-redis:
        image: redis:7.0
        container_name: gpstracker-redis
        restart: unless-stopped
        networks:
            - gpstracker-network
        healthcheck:
            test: redis-cli ping
            interval: 5s
            retries: 15

    gpstracker-app:
        image: gpstracker-app:latest
        container_name: gpstracker-app
        restart: unless-stopped
        depends_on:
            gpstracker-mysql:
                condition: service_healthy
            gpstracker-redis:
                condition: service_healthy
        build:
            context: ..
            dockerfile: ./docker/Dockerfile
        ports:
            - "8080:80"
            - "8091:8091"
        expose:
            - "8080"
            - "8091"
        networks:
            - gpstracker-network
        tty: true

networks:
  gpstracker-network:
    name: gpstracker-network
    driver: bridge

When I build this file with:
sudo docker compose -f docker/docker-compose.yml pull
sudo docker compose -f docker/docker-compose.yml up --force-recreate --build -d

I get:
PDO::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo for gpstracker-my  
sql failed: Name or service not known

And no container was created:
sudo docker ps -a

CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND   CREATED   STATUS    PORTS     NAMES

But I have the images and network:
sudo docker image ls

REPOSITORY   TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED       SIZE
mysql        8.0       c5f0c876cdb1   13 days ago   567MB
redis        7.0       f86d36f62d00   5 weeks ago   109MB

sudo docker network ls

NETWORK ID     NAME                 DRIVER    SCOPE
b9c1cd6e9b9c   bridge               bridge    local
e1d6002a7558   gpstracker-network   bridge    local
6eb0cc92d744   host                 host      local
eb6f8188ad5f   none                 null      local

What's the problem with my docker-compose.yml definition?
UPDATE: Build process is:
Pulling gpstracker-mysql ... done
Pulling gpstracker-redis ... done
Pulling gpstracker-app   ... done
WARNING: Some service image(s) must be built from source by running:
    docker compose build gpstracker-app
Creating network "gpstracker-network" with driver "bridge"
Building gpstracker-app
[+] Building 206.6s (21/22)                                                                                                                                                                             docker:default
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                              0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 953B                                                                                                                                                                              0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/php:8.3                                                                                                                                                        1.4s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                                 0.0s
 => => transferring context: 209B                                                                                                                                                                                 0.0s
 => [ 1/18] FROM docker.io/library/php:8.3@sha256:83ba95916699325dc60f7e8678c5534b902c8d143b2e64508e7fc72eb6965a9d                                                                                               19.4s
 => => resolve docker.io/library/php:8.3@sha256:83ba95916699325dc60f7e8678c5534b902c8d143b2e64508e7fc72eb6965a9d                                                                                                  0.0s
 => => sha256:76afcdc8655129b4b8245d674820f06020b8a54f3db6c8d9147234b985f3c923 225B / 225B                                                                                                                        0.5s
 => => sha256:83ba95916699325dc60f7e8678c5534b902c8d143b2e64508e7fc72eb6965a9d 1.86kB / 1.86kB                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => => sha256:09f376ebb190216b0459f470e71bec7b5dfa611d66bf008492b40dcc5f1d8eae 29.15MB / 29.15MB                                                                                                                  8.2s
 => => sha256:ceed4541c527d7a443908138f347495ec250ba7a1e70d8dd6b567464064ee115 104.36MB / 104.36MB                                                                                                               16.3s
 => => sha256:872e74e61f74f4f8bb1356f0cd6cde2027fcb7ae5fc56ade405cba0aacda1ebd 2.20kB / 2.20kB                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => => sha256:6733b3877226499319c9b321d35cdfd165f0c22b10b6ccff9d3808ae239f4a39 9.92kB / 9.92kB                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => => sha256:9ec84be954b08b2782f93426799a585ad7b33b0e7d57b3f725218d450ea5d20d 270B / 270B                                                                                                                        0.9s
 => => sha256:fe4039e5428ff8adc82d3350a85e2c7824985a6c724c394745cad5bf64b7db2a 12.77MB / 12.77MB                                                                                                                  3.9s
 => => sha256:833c1322b1abde332a52537e1d29545483d39edc5a42e82d6ceaf1ad35983e3f 491B / 491B                                                                                                                        4.1s
 => => sha256:22c7c20cb2c7f99ac08c387fa6a30e4e1b7c6a5e1783facf0e67ae12996c1e39 36.28MB / 36.28MB                                                                                                                 10.6s
 => => extracting sha256:09f376ebb190216b0459f470e71bec7b5dfa611d66bf008492b40dcc5f1d8eae                                                                                                                         0.6s
 => => sha256:195513f643617b5e66abb72375b47d76e8677477cafb1f13ec0081341bd238b7 2.45kB / 2.45kB                                                                                                                    8.4s
 => => sha256:ffeb288a2853bb39b2ca35742936642a542154ef14c645e5e77ea12de9575056 245B / 245B                                                                                                                        8.6s
 => => extracting sha256:76afcdc8655129b4b8245d674820f06020b8a54f3db6c8d9147234b985f3c923                                                                                                                         0.0s
 => => extracting sha256:ceed4541c527d7a443908138f347495ec250ba7a1e70d8dd6b567464064ee115                                                                                                                         1.9s
 => => extracting sha256:9ec84be954b08b2782f93426799a585ad7b33b0e7d57b3f725218d450ea5d20d                                                                                                                         0.0s
 => => extracting sha256:fe4039e5428ff8adc82d3350a85e2c7824985a6c724c394745cad5bf64b7db2a                                                                                                                         0.1s
 => => extracting sha256:833c1322b1abde332a52537e1d29545483d39edc5a42e82d6ceaf1ad35983e3f                                                                                                                         0.0s
 => => extracting sha256:22c7c20cb2c7f99ac08c387fa6a30e4e1b7c6a5e1783facf0e67ae12996c1e39                                                                                                                         0.7s
 => => extracting sha256:195513f643617b5e66abb72375b47d76e8677477cafb1f13ec0081341bd238b7                                                                                                                         0.0s
 => => extracting sha256:ffeb288a2853bb39b2ca35742936642a542154ef14c645e5e77ea12de9575056                                                                                                                         0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                                                                 0.2s
 => => transferring context: 26.59MB                                                                                                                                                                              0.2s
 => [ 2/18] RUN apt-get update -y                                                                                                                                                                                 3.2s
 => [ 3/18] RUN apt-get upgrade -y                                                                                                                                                                                0.9s
 => [ 4/18] RUN apt install -yqq --no-install-recommends     cron default-mysql-client git     libbz2-dev libicu-dev libldb-dev libonig-dev     libxslt-dev libzip-dev procps unzip                               9.9s
 => [ 5/18] RUN rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*                                                                                                                                                                       0.3s
 => [ 6/18] RUN apt clean && apt autoclean && apt autoremove --assume-yes                                                                                                                                         0.2s
 => [ 7/18] RUN pecl install redis                                                                                                                                                                               29.0s
 => [ 8/18] RUN docker-php-ext-install bcmath bz2 intl mbstring opcache pdo_mysql pcntl sockets xsl zip                                                                                                         123.8s
 => [ 9/18] RUN docker-php-ext-enable redis                                                                                                                                                                       0.4s
 => [10/18] COPY ./docker/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/                                                                                                                                                             0.0s
 => [11/18] COPY ./docker/crontab /etc/cron.d/crontab                                                                                                                                                             0.0s
 => [12/18] RUN crontab -u www-data /etc/cron.d/crontab                                                                                                                                                           0.2s
 => [13/18] RUN chown www-data:www-data /var/www                                                                                                                                                                  0.2s
 => [14/18] WORKDIR /app                                                                                                                                                                                          0.1s
 => [15/18] COPY --chown=www-data:www-data ./ /app                                                                                                                                                                0.3s
 => [16/18] RUN git config --global --add safe.directory /app                                                                                                                                                     0.2s
 => ERROR [17/18] RUN ./composer install --no-dev --optimize-autoloader --classmap-authoritative                                                                                                                 16.8s

UPDATE 2: Executing build service by service, the containers are created but the app can not be built (the error is the same):
sudo docker compose -f docker/docker-compose.yml up --build -d gpstracker-mysql
sudo docker compose -f docker/docker-compose.yml up --build -d gpstracker-redis
sudo docker compose -f docker/docker-compose.yml up --build -d gpstracker-app

sudo docker ps -a

CONTAINER ID   IMAGE       COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS                   PORTS                 NAMES
98c18d7961ce   redis:7.0   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   9 minutes ago   Up 8 minutes (healthy)   6379/tcp              gpstracker-redis
4f9c1d76de24   mysql:8.0   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   9 minutes ago   Up 9 minutes (healthy)   3306/tcp, 33060/tcp   gpstracker-mysql

Thanks!

Can you please run docker compose build to see if the error occurs at build time or at run-time?

@HansKilian no errors, the unique error is when the gpstracker-app is building the Dockerfile that have a PHP script that need to connect to database for migrations.

Why do you say "no errors"? The last line of your build log shows an error. Your database isn't started until run-time, so if your build process needs access to the database, then it won't be available. This is a common problem with ORMs in relation to docker compose.

When I create every service one by one, I get the containers (see UPDATE 2) but anyway when I build gpstracker-app it can not connect to gpstracker-mysql service. sudo docker logs gpstracker-mysql show the service running.

If I understand correctly, your gpstracker-app service depends on gpstracker-mysql at build time right? Unfortunately, docker compose does not support building services with dependencies as specified here.

It was working before change the docker compose command to docker-compose

It doesn't really matter if you start the database before building. The build process is not attached to the bridge network, so it can't connect using the service name. What you can do is start the database but with it's port mapped to the host. And then use localhost as the database hostname during the build. Once the image is built, you can then use the service name when running the container. It might be an idea to build the app image using 'normal' docker build since using compose both for building and running can be confusing.

As a little sidenote, docker compose is actually the newer and preferred way of using Docker Compose instead of the older docker-compose tool according to the docs. If it was working with docker compose before, why switch to docker-compose?

Sorry, my mistake, I'm actually using docker compose instead of docker-compose.

As @moonstar-x say, I need to move the database related commands from Dockerfile to init.sh script.
